# JSON_PARSER_ERROR: Cannot deserialize instance of date from VALUE_STRING

Tags: soap-api, date, datetime, csv, python

I am trying to insert date from csv file into Salesforce (Sandbox for now).

I have a csv file that has this format YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.

Bottom is screenshot from a csv file.

[image]

I tried inserting into a custom field of **Date** and **DateTime** data formats.

When I ran Python file to insert data (using Linux), I am getting same error on both occasions (Date or DateTime).

'JSON_PARSER_ERROR' Cannot deserizlize instance of date from VALUE_STRING.

This is not System.JSONException error.

[image]

Is this something to be fixed on the format of csv file?

I read other cases, and it mentioned something about standard ISO 8601 format, but I am trying to go with simple **YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss** format.

Comment: I need to have hh:mm:ss format,  and I do not have quotes nor trailing comma.

Comment: It looks like you may be trying to put the data into a Date field and not a date time

Comment: I tried both Date and DateTime field, and same error message.

Answer (score 1):

You must use one of the following formats for json to be able to parse. 
Leave the 'T' and 'Z' characters as they are.

YYYY-MM-DD
YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss+hh:mm
YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss-hh:mm
YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ

EG: 2047-07-24T10:28:00+00:00

I'd open with excel and use a combination of left, right and concatenate functions until the formatting was correct, and then save as values and try loading again.

Comment: I am trying to not open csv file in Excel, but leave as it is. Also, since I am trying to insert into Date or DateTime data format, shouldn't I use the format listed in https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Data-Loader-Import-data-for-Date-or-Date-Time-field-1327108684799&language=en_US&type=1

Comment: I found the solution. I need to use either of these formats to work. 
• YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ
• YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sssZ